# Capture Random Frame from an Online hosted MP4 file

Tags: python, video, thumbnails, mp4

Here, I have a website where I am scraping MP4 files, my problem is that I need to generate normal thumbnails with specific measurements, I searched for the last and tried many things, nothing worked.

I want something fast and can randomly pick a frame from half the video or the duration I provide.

I found [thumb-gen](https://github.com/truethari/thumb-gen), but I think it doesn't support online usage...

Comment: If you say _"I tried many things, nothing worked."_ then no-one knows that you didn't already try OpenCV or FFmpeg...

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution:

```py
import cv2

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(MP4URL)
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
while success:
  cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file      
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  print('Read a new frame: ', success)
  count += 1
```